# Can a magnifying glass work on EM radiation other than visible light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, lenses

A magnifying glass is a [convex lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_%28optics%29#Types_of_simple_lenses) which allows us to bend visible light, thus the image of the object appears larger.

My question is, can a magnifying glass work on the rest of the [electromagnetic spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it all depends on the refractive index of glass at the wavelengths you are interested in.

In the IR (infra red) I think ZnS is a material of choice for lenses and windows - but I know KBr can be used - Potassium Bromide - you have to be careful with KBr as it dissolves in water.... Above the UV it becomes difficult to use windows as all materials are damaged by light above about 10 eV per photon, which is the same as abou 120 nm (very roughly). The window material that goes highest in energy is LiF - Lithium Fluoride.

Above the UV when lenses can't be used focussing mirrors can be used e.g. at Synchrotrons. Mirrors can also be used in the IR range - a problem with lenses is that chromatic aberration is caused by different wavelengths having slightly different refractive indicies and this leads to a lens having different focal lengths for different wavelengths (or colours) of light - An advantage with mirrors is that focal lengths are wavelength independent - Mirrors have focal lengths that only depend on geometry. Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

ZnCl2 refractive index: 1.37536 - 1.37646 at 20°C
For ZnS: 1.658 (anhydrous), 1.4357 (heptahydrate)

Both zinc compounds are okay in terms of refraction